# No "unaligned" apks are generated with gradle plugin 2.2.0, breaking Spoon runner

Tags: android, spoon

Using android gradle plugin `2.2.0`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0"
    }
}
```

and running `./gradlew assembleDebug assembleDebugAndroidTest`:

with `2.2.0`:

```
app-debug.apk
app-debug-androidTest.apk
```

with `2.1.3`:

```
app-debug.apk
app-debug-unaligned.apk
app-debug-androidTest.apk
app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
```

Based on this google issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212591 and comment here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212591#c15:

> Hi, we don't generate unaligned apks any more. As part of the
>   improvements to speed things, we generate the apk already aligned. So,
>   instead of two, you just get the final one.

Spoon requires these "unaligned" apks to run it's test runner:

```
java -jar spoon-runner-1.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
    --debug --fail-on-failure --adb-timeout 90 --no-animations \
    --apk app-debug.apk \
    --test-apk app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
```

Error:

```
12:06:48 I/InstrumentationResultParser: test run failed: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError''
2016-09-23 12:06:48 [STRL.testRunStarted] testCount=0 runName=<>.test
2016-09-23 12:06:48 [STRL.testRunFailed] errorMessage=Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'
2016-09-23 12:06:48 [STRL.testRunEnded] elapsedTime=0
12:06:48 I/XmlResultReporter: XML test result file generated at /<>/spoon-output/junit-reports/emulator-5554.xml. Total tests 0,
```

It looks like Spoon only takes in the "unaligned".

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Instrumentation APK path does not exist.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner$Builder.setInstrumentationApk(SpoonRunner.java:360)
    at com.squareup.spoon.SpoonRunner.main(SpoonRunner.java:657)
```

Comment: And you want to generate unaligned APKs?

Comment: @antonio It looks like Square needs unaligned. See here https://github.com/square/spoon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before 2.2, the gradle plugin would generate an unaligned apk and then run zipalign to align it. So, two apks were produced one with "-unaligned" and one, aligned without any particular markings.

With 2.2 there were many improvements in the build pipeline related to this:

- APKs are now built incrementally, meaning when a single file is changed, only that file is updated in the APK.
- APKs are generated aligned, no need for an extra alignment step.

The last of these two enable V2 signatures in the APK (https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2.html): full-APK signatures that are resistant to any changes in the APK (and faster to verify). This means zipalign can no longer run on APKs that have these signatures enabled.

So, to make the story short, starting with 2.2 packaging is faster, incremental and does not generate unnecessary unaligned APKs.

Comment: This is correct and confirmed here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223551#c4. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up zipalign to false inside gradle file?

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        zipAlignEnabled false 
    }
}
```

You can also specify multiple buildTypes if you want

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        zipAlignEnabled false 
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: I did but it did not generate the APKs.

Comment: How did you build your apk? Using this path : Build/Build Apk ?

Comment: I posted in my question: `./gradlew assembleDebug assembleDebugAndroidTest`. Did you test this locally?

Comment: Yes, but I used Build/Generate Signed APK which let me decide which build type I want... Then I choose debug as type and I choose debug in the list of build type

Comment: I was asking if you tested the gradle code you posted. It does not generated "unaligned" apk files.